# Possibility of: $site->self::filter_name

Tags: php, object

I need to use: $site->self::filter_name

Obviously that returns a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in` error

Thanks

Edit: Answer is: $site->{self::filter_name}

Comment: You should post an answer yourself and accept that answer instead of editing the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: `$site->{self::filter_name}`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Classname::$filter_name`. `Classname` is the class which `$site` is an instance of.

If you don't know the class of the instance, you may use this (as of PHP 5.3!):

```
$className = get_class($instance);
$className::$staticProperty;
```

Comment: Its a seperate object.

Ive managed to fix it via: $site->{self::filter_name}

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood you.